# Identity server 4 on the same url as MVC client

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is it possible to run Identity Server 4 on the same url as the MVC client, in the same host using nginx? For example Identity Server would run on localhost/id/ and mvc client on localhost/api

In MVC client there is port 5000. I can easily change this to http://localhost/id

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; // <== HERE
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
```

But how do I make Identity Server process only requests to localhost/id ?
Preferably I would want to do all in asp.net app and don;t use reverse proxy or anything else

Comment: IdentityServer4 is an implementation of oidc where the autorization server is seperated from the resources and apps. Seems to me that Ids4 is not the tool to use in this case. AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server (ASOS) or OpenIdDict may be a better alternative.

Comment: Have a look at [`Map`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-run-and-map) - you can set path-specific middleware pipelines. If you need more help, let me know and I'll describe it in an answer.